# Deleting Items From A listView

Tags: c#

```
    private void ListTask()
    {
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
        foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.MainWindowTitle)).ToList())
            listView1.Items.Add(process.ProcessName);
    }
    private List<Process> GetRunning()
    {
        return Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.MainWindowTitle)).ToList();
    }

    private List<Process> prevProcesses;

    private List<Process> GetClosed()
    {
        var current = GetRunning();
        var result = this.prevProcesses.Except(current);
        this.prevProcesses = current;
        return result.ToList();
    }
```

I have the following code. I want to delete items from a listView based on what it returns, something like this:

```
listView1.Items.Remove(GetClosed());
```

How could I do this?

Comment: What's in the ListView? Specifically.

Comment: Yeah, show us your `Add` please

Comment: You should rebind the listview with the list of currently running processes instead of trying to removing items from it.